# Problems with "no space left on device" on MergerFS fuse mount?

Tags: mount, fstab

I’ve created two 4gb sparse images to test mergerfs. I’ve formatted and mounted the sparse images via fstab, and they are writable. I then configured fstab to mount a mergerfs fuse drive. It mounts without error - or so it seems - but I can’t do anything with it. I get the following error:

> Error while copying “file”. There was an error copying the file into
> /mnt/mergerfs. Error opening file "/mnt/mergerfs/file”: No space left
> on device

I’ve changes ownership and changed permissions on the mount. As I mentioned, I can copy data fine into the underlying data drives. I think there is an issue with the fuse mount, but I can’t figure out what it is. I’ve tried mounting as sudo and as user. I’ve also updated to the latest version of mergerfs. I’m on Ubuntu 2022.04.02.

The fstab entry is:

```
/mnt/disk1:/mnt/disk2 /mnt/mergerfs fuse.mergerfs cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs 0 0
```

Perhaps the problem is disk1 and disk2 are btrfs-formatted sparse images for testing purposes, but I have also tried this in a VM with virtual disks and I’ve run into the same exact problem.

Any ideas how to fix this and get the mergerfs mount operational?

Answer (score 0):

> two 4gb sparse images

The [default value](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#options) for `minfreespace` is 4G. Set it to something lower (like zero).